# Forced-Directed-Graph Fruchterman and Reingold t and disp (number and vector?)

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to implement the algorithm of Fruchterman and Reingold and have a problem in understanding the types of the "t" (temperature) and "disp" (displacement) because on the last loop they calcualte the minimum of t and disp. Is t not a number and disp a vector? How can I calculate the minimum of a number and a vector?

Link: [www.cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf#page=5](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/rtamassi/gdhandbook/chapters/force-directed.pdf#page=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I have no previous experience of this algorithm, but it seems to me as if you are right and that this is a typo, where actually *min(|v.disp|, t)* was meant.

I find some support for my claim looking at an implementation [here](https://legacy.philipbjorge.com/archived_wp_blog/www.philipbjorge.com/2011/11/11/3d-fruchterman-reingold/index.html), which recognises some typos in the original pseudo-code. Please verify yourself before taking my word for it.